# Python - matching a string within a string explicitly

Tags: python, string, match

I am trying to match specific router interfaces. However, I am finding the below confusing, when searching for specific interface numbers, it is matching on the first condition, when i think it should be matching on the second condition:

```
string = ["TenGigE0/0/0/0.12", "TenGigE0/0/0/1.46", "TenGigE0/0/0/15.55"]

for item in string:
    if 'TenGigE0/0/0/0' in item or 'TenGigE0/0/0/1' in item:
        print("Yes")
    elif 'TenGigE0/0/0/15' in item:
        print("cool")
```

Output is:

```
Yes
Yes
Yes
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Reverse the order of if/elif conditions.

Comment: This is because "'TenGigE0/0/0/15.55" and "'TenGigE0/0/0/1.46" starts with "'TenGigE0/0/0/1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the if-statements around:

```py
string = ["TenGigE0/0/0/0.12", "TenGigE0/0/0/1.46", "TenGigE0/0/0/15.55"]

for item in string:
    if 'TenGigE0/0/0/15' in item:
        print("cool")
    elif ('TenGigE0/0/0/0' in item) or ('TenGigE0/0/0/1' in item):
        print("Yes")
```

Will get you:

```
Yes
Yes
cool
```

Since `TenGigE0/0/0/15` contains `TenGigE0/0/0/1` too, and if you check for `TenGigE0/0/0/1` before checking for `TenGigE0/0/0/15` the first if-statement results in True

Answer (score 1):

Let's visualise this:

- `'TenGigE0/0/0/0'` in `'TenGigE0/0/0/0.12'` is true, because `'TenGigE0/0/0/0'` is a substring of `'TenGigE0/0/0/0.12'`:

  ```
  TenGigE0/0/0/0.12
  TenGigE0/0/0/0
  ```
- `'TenGigE0/0/0/1'` in `'TenGigE0/0/0/1.46'` is true, because `'TenGigE0/0/0/1'` is a substring of `'TenGigE0/0/0/1.46'`:

  ```
  TenGigE0/0/0/1.46
  TenGigE0/0/0/1
  ```
- Same for `'TenGigE0/0/0/15.55'`:

  ```
  TenGigE0/0/0/15.55
  TenGigE0/0/0/1
  ```

`if` statement executes the code after the *first* condition that is `True`, so even though `'TenGigE0/0/0/15' in 'TenGigE0/0/0/15.55'` is True, `'TenGigE0/0/0/1' in 'TenGigE0/0/0/15.55'` was *first*, so that's what got executed.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in other answers, `'/1'` is a substring of `'/15'`.

Another solution is to use **regex** with a word bound `\b` and a group for `'0'` OR `'1'`:

```
import re

string = ["TenGigE0/0/0/0.12", "TenGigE0/0/0/1.46", "TenGigE0/0/0/15.55"]
for item in string:
    if re.match(r'TenGigE0/0/0/(0|1)\b', item):
        print("Yes")
    elif re.match(r'TenGigE0/0/0/15\b', item):
        print("cool")
```

Output:

```
Yes
Yes
cool
```